# Can MongoDB push data to MS-SQL

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java, mongodb-c

I have a requirement where mongodb needs to push its data to MS-SQL server once in a day.  I dont want to use java in the middle.  Is there a way that MongoDB can it call MS-SQL stored procedure.

Any help on this regard is highly appreciated

Comment: use a message queue like http://www.rabbitmq.com/ for handle this

Answer (score 1):

No.  mongodb can not call out like that.  You'll need some code running to bridge between the two databases.